# need a way to detect page postback

Tags: php

I am a php beginner. I want every time when I run my project to create a unique file and for this I used uniqid(). Only every time when my page is reloaded to display the new data recieved from  sever, it will create a new file with unic name. But I want to keep the first file created until the application is closed.

This is my code:

```
$uniq = uniqid();
if(!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime'])){
  setcookie('firsttime', 'no');
  $num = $uniq;
  $myfile = 'file/'.$num.'.txt';
  if(file_exists($myfile) == FALSE){
    $fo = fopen($myfile, 'w')or die();
    $code = '<form action = "" method = "post">';
    fwrite($fo, $code, strlen($code)) ;
    fclose($fo);
  }else{
    unlink($myfile);
    $file = new File();
  } 
}
```

Can someoane help me?

Comment: the code I wrote works the problem is it runs every the the page reload and I need it to run only the first time.I need to a way to run this code only if it is not a PostBack

Comment: Make sure that cookie is set in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, if I read that correctly, that you should be assigning the cookie to be the unique name, then using that instead of generating a new one every time.
Now, you say you want it to run if it is not a postback. By this I assume you mean the posting of a form, so you only run it once, then if a user posts the form on the page then you do not create a new id, you instead use the one that is currently in use...

```
if(!isset($_POST['some_form_element']))
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE['firsttime'])){
      $myfile = 'file/'.$_COOKIE['firsttime'].'.txt';

    }
    else
    {
        $uniq = uniqid();
        setcookie('firsttime', $uniq);
        $myfile = 'file/'.$uniq.'.txt';
    }

    if(file_exists($myfile) == FALSE){
        $fo = fopen($myfile, 'w')or die();
        $code = '<form action = "" method = "post">';
        fwrite($fo, $code, strlen($code)) ;
        fclose($fo);
    }else{
        unlink($myfile);
        $file = new File();
    } 
}
```

where "some_form_element" is any element in your form, or a hidden field, etc. It's probably best to use something specific and not just !$_POST.

If I am wrong about your needs let me know. I can update.